# How to send dummy data using dss server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I heard that we can send dummy data in web server.So we don't need actually database.How we send dummy data using Wso2 Data Service server ?

Comment: This would be a better question for http://serverfault.com or maybe http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom data sources feature to create your custom data source which you can give set of dummy data 
refer [custom data sources in WSO2 DSS](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS300/Custom+Data+Sources) for more infomation and [InMemoryDSSSample](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/products/dss/3.0.0/modules/samples/dbs/inmemory/InMemoryDSSample.dbs) for a sample ds